# Can I use unstable version of angular ui-grid for production?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I was customizing the CSS using the Customizer option provided in the ui-grid site.I was using the stable version (v3.0.0-RC.18) with this customized styles, extra scrolls are coming up in the grid.

But if I am using the unstable version with these customized styles, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion; UI-Grid does not currently have a stable release. The stable drop-down there is a placeholder and points to some old code. If you go to the project page it says that UI-Grid is still "pre-beta": https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid but I know having something say "Stable" is confusing.

For now, the "Unstable" setting will be the most current option.

Comment: Which folder among the /release should I pick up?

Comment: @ashok_khuman You can either install via bower, or look for the latest release in the ui-grid.info repository: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-rc.20